# Synology LDAP and OSX Network Homes

Tags: macos, automount, nfs

Is there anyone out there using a Synology DiskStation running Directory Server (their LDAP implementation) to provide authentication AND network homes for OSX?  I've tried setting it up and have hit a roadblock with getting the OSX clients to automount the NFS export where the home folders reside on Synology.  I would love to know if anyone out there is doing this and how they configured the clients to automount the homes.

Comment: Can we safely assume that LDAP users with local home folders and local users with NFS home folders both work on your setup? Also - listing versions of synology and OS X in the body of the question might be useful for someone to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mounting the volumes and then adding them to their LogIn items?
I have my iTunes library on my Synology and use that to get the volume mounted every time I restart (which is only for system updates that need restarting.)